# Use Javascript prototype in php script

Tags: javascript, php, prototype

I have a javascript prototype:

```
function Shape(width, height){
  this.width = width || 0;
  this.height = height || 0; 
}

Shape.prototype.draw = function() {
    //...
};
```

And a php script, that prints javascript code:

```
print "<script>\r\n"
    ."var x = function(){\r\n"
        ."var r = new Shape(100, 100);\r\n"
        ."r.draw();\r\n"
    ."};\r\n"
    ."x();\r\n"
    ."x = undefined;\r\n"
    ."</script>";
```

But the generated script code doesn't works. When I use an alert message instead of this in generated function, the message will shown. So, what do I wrong or how I could get it to work?

Thank you for answers.

---

I am sorry, I was a little bit too imprecise. I thought, some informations would be unimportant. So, my prototype declaration is in an external javascript file.
Now I found a solution for my problem: I write the generated script in a new javascript file and bind this file into main html. Then I had to set a local variable to global.. that was the main problem... * embarrassed *

Comment: You'll have a much easier time if you just have php render the javascript, not concoct a string and printing it: eg, `<?php if (1 == 1){ ?> <script>...</script><?php } ?>` if you're printing different values conditionally. Otherwise, just close the php tag and write the script normally.

Answer (score 0):

The code works fine when I created a test.php with the content:

```
<script>function Shape(width, height){
  this.width = width || 0;
  this.height = height || 0; 
}

Shape.prototype.draw = function() {
alert('Test');
};</script>
<?php
print "<script>\r\n"
    ."var x = function(){\r\n"
        ."var r = new Shape(100, 100);\r\n"
        ."r.draw();\r\n"
    ."};\r\n"
    ."x();\r\n"
    ."x = undefined;\r\n"
    ."</script>";?>
```

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry, it was a bad example from me. My original script has many lines. But I found a solution, see at the top of thread.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way to "execute" javascript code from PHP:

```
<?
//PHP code...
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
var x = function()
{
    var r = new Shape(100, 100);
    r.draw();
};

x();
</script>

<?
//More PHP
?>
```